# How to handle C++ class construct failure in Lua

Tags: c++, class, constructor, lua, swig

I use SWIG to bind C++ classes so I can use them in Lua.

I wonder if it's possible to handle construction failure of C++ class in Lua.

For example, I have the following `Test` class which tries to get the Userdata when it's constructed.

```
void *getUserdata(lua_State *L, const char *key)
{
    lua_pushstring(L, key);
    lua_gettable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    return lua_touserdata(L, -1);
}

class Test
{
public:
    Test(lua_State *L)
    :data(static_cast<MyData *>(getUserdata(L, "my_name"))){};

    void setDataNum(int num)
    {
        data->num = num;
    }
private:
       MyData *data;
};
```

However, if `getUserdata()` returns `nullptr`, calling `setDataNum()` crashes my application.

I wonder if there's any way to detect and handle the construction failure(`data` becoming `nullptr` in this case) so the class won't create in Lua.

Comment: Can you create a lua class that lets you check the state of userData that you call first from lua before calling the class created by `getUserdata`?

Comment: You say you are using SWIG but you are manipulating the Lua stack directly and the example you posted is not a SWIG interface file.  To me it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm sorry, I have this code in my SWIG interface file: `%typemap(default) (lua_State *L) 
{
    $1 = L;
}` This is how it can manipulate the Lua stack directly. Maybe I should create a typemap for the class `Test` to handle exception?

Comment: Why do you save things as userdata when you could just keep them as a private member of `Test`?  What's in the userdata at `"my_name"`?  You are kind of defeating the purpose of SWIG which is there to give you a clean boundary between C++ and the scripting language.

Comment: @cuinjune You accepted my answer but didn't upvote.  Is there anything where you find my answer to be lacking?

Comment: @HenriMenke Not at all, It's just that I can't upvote anything because I don't have 15 reputation yet. Your answer is great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @cuinjune I see.  I also failed to upvote your question which I did now, which should bump you beyond the 15 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to error handling would be to check for the error.  From the [Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_touserdata):

> ```
> void *lua_touserdata (lua_State *L, int index);
> ```
>
> If the value at the given index is a full userdata, returns its block address. If the value is a light userdata, returns its pointer. Otherwise, returns `NULL`.

That means we can easily check whether the call succeeded by checking `data` for being `NULL`.  Then we can act accordingly, I choose to throw an exception.

**`test.hpp`**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdexcept>

#include <lua.hpp>

struct MyData {
    int num;
};

void *getUserdata(lua_State *L, const char *key) {
    lua_pushstring(L, key);
    lua_gettable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    return lua_touserdata(L, -1);
}

class Test {
public:
    Test(lua_State *L)
        : data(static_cast<MyData *>(getUserdata(L, "my_name"))) {
        if (data == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid userdata at \"my_name\"");
        }
    };

    void setDataNum(int num) { data->num = num; }

private:
    MyData *data;
};
```

This exception is not digestible by Lua and by default the interpreter will just crash with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'`.  This is not so nice and we rather want to have the exception converted to a Lua error.  SWIG comes with [support for that](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_stl_exceptions).

**`test.i`**

```
%module example
%{
#include "test.hpp"
%}

%include <exception.i>
%exception {
    try {
        $action
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, e.what());
    }
}

%typemap(default) (lua_State *L) { $1 = L; }
%include "test.hpp"
```

Lua doesn't have exceptions and thus no `try`-`catch` blocks.  Instead Lua has the concept of a protected call with `pcall`.  This will return a flag whether the call was successful and the result of the call or an error.

```lua
local example = require("example")
local success, c = pcall(example.Test)
if (success) then
    c:setDataNum(1)
else
    print(c)
end
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -c++ -lua test.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2 -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o example.so -llua5.2
$ lua5.2 test.lua
SWIG_RuntimeError:invalid userdata at "my_name"
```